# DNS Leak Test via Command-Line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, dns

How can I perform a DNS leak test on a headless linux server? I've manually set up VPN split-tunneling on it, and would like to ensure that it is working properly.

With a GUI, I normally do it with an online tool like [dnsleaktest.com](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/), but I was wondering if there's a way to do it via the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [this script](https://github.com/macvk/dnsleaktest).

1. Download dnsleaktest.sh:
   `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/macvk/dnsleaktest/master/dnsleaktest.sh -o dnsleaktest.sh`
2. Make it executable:
   `chmod +x dnsleaktest.sh`
3. Run it:
   `./dnsleaktest.sh`

If you want to be able to [run it from anywhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427818/how-to-run-scripts-without-typing-the-full-path/527008#527008), create a symbolic link to the script:
`sudo ln -s /full/path/to/dnsleaktest.sh /usr/local/bin/name_of_new_command`